# Swift: How to disable a button

Tags: swift, button

I'm trying to disable a button for certain amount of time, but have an issue. My procedure is below:

1. I have 3 buttons and all buttons are enabled
2. After one button is clicked, disable all buttons. In the meantime, sending data via Bluetooth...
3. Enable all buttons after finishing sending data.

My goal is to prevent button click when sending data via Bluetooth. I tried to use `Button.userInteractionEnabled = false`  and  `Button.enabled = false`, but  it will go to button action handler(The one that I press during data sending period) again whenever I enable button after finishing sending data. Does any one know how to disable buttons permanently for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Are you saying that the click is handled, but with a delay? (When using `isEnabled = false`.)

Comment: Actual code needed here.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is disable the button upon clicked and then somehow enable it when the data transfer it's done.

If this data transfer is called asynchronously, it will probably have a parameter where you can send in a **completion block**:

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
sendData(data) {
    success in
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

If it doesn't accept a **completion block** as a parameter, it might work in a different way, such as using **notifications** (firing a notification with a specific name):

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
sendData(data)

// adding the observer that will watch for the fired notification
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didFinishSendingData(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NOTIFICATION NAME GOES HERE"), object: nil)

func didFinishSendingData(_ notification: Notification?) {
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

We could definitely help more if you post a sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why can you achieve this on the `main thread` with an `activityIndicator` like below:

```
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.frame = view.frame
    activityIndicator.center = view.center
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    //start activity indicator
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    //send your data via bluetooth on main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //put your sending via bluetooth code here with a completion handler when completes
        //then in the completion handler, put below line
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
```